# How do I conditionally format a column in VBA based on each cell's value and a fixed cell's value?

Tags: vba, date, excel, conditional-formatting

I need to set up conditional formatting for a column where each cell is highlighted based on two other values derived from cells within the spreadsheet.  The values are dates.  This needs to be done in VBA (for lots of reasons: the code works with other software and clears out contents, groups lines together, etc.).  I have failed with many methods and am currently failing with the following:

```
Sheets("Trial").Activate
With ActiveSheet.Range("E:E")
.Select
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="="
& (Range("P1").Value - 1), Formula2:="=" & (Range("P1").Value + 6)
.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With
```

Ultimately, I need cells in column E to turn red when the value is between P1-1 and P1+6.  Even if I extract this code and run it by itself, I am getting a procedure call error.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
Sheets("Trial").Activate
With Columns("E:E")
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(E1>=$P$1-1,E1<=$P$1+6)"
.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 255
End With
```

Comment: I am still getting an error.  I should add that the values are dates and will edit the question to reflect that.  I had attempted to use date variables and embed them in the formula as listed above with &'s but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to use conditional formatting if you don't want to. You could use a for loop to loop through all the values in column E. Take this as an example.

```
Dim TotalERows As Long
Dim EValue As Long
Dim LowerBound As Long
Dim UpperBound As Long
LowerBound = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("P1").Value - 2
UpperBound = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("P1").Value + 7
TotalERows = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For I = 1 To TotalERows
    EValue = Range("E" & I).Value
        If LowerBound < EValue And EValue < UpperBound Then
            Range("E" & I).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
Next I
```

Comment: That would indeed be an issue. I just thought this method might be an interesting alternative if necessary.